# PHP variable inside the inline css

Tags: php, css

I need to display the elearning progress of each user. This value is retrieved from the database using PHP. The progress bar i'm using is with bootstrap and it requires that I put the progress value inside the width property found in the inline css.
Is this possible?
This is what I've tried but it's not displaying anything:

**CODES**

```
<?php
            include('../../dbconnect.php');
            $id = $_SESSION['ID'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM progress WHERE lectureID=1 AND chapterID = 1 AND currentLevel='novice' AND ID = '$id';";

            $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('Query failed');

            while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $value = $result['chapterPerc'];
                ?>

                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
                     aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $value ?> %;"> <!--tried this-->
                </div>
                <?php
            } //while loop closes here

            ?>
        </div>
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Yes.  Should work fine.  Verified that `$value` is what you expect?  What does the source output look like?  Might just be the space before the `%`?

Comment: Try removing the space between `<?php echo $value ?> ` and `%` in the inline CSS.

Comment: Good opportunity to consider starting to use `<?= $value ?>`...  Keeps things neater I find.  Just an observation.

Comment: Besides comments/answer. Make sure the session was started.

Comment: Does it actually return a value? just echo out first the value before putting it in the progress bar. Just to make sure. There may be a return, but if the field you specified is wrong when you assign it to the value variable, (mistakes are easily made) it may come up empty

Comment: The problem was with the query itself there's no chapterID 1 should have written 2. Thanks for the insight. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop since you are printing a single row:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM progress WHERE lectureID='1'  
        AND currentLevel='novice' AND ID = '$id'";//; removed
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('Query failed');  
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
?>
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
 aria-valuenow="<?php echo $result['chapterPerc'];?>" 
 aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" 
 style="width:<?php echo $result['chapterPerc'];?>%;"> 
</div>
```

Hope this will work. I have tested and it is working fine.

Comment: It was a simple mistake with the query there's no chapterID 1 in the table. All fixed now. Amended my code to yours. Thanks.

Comment: @Damini, please click the tick icon above to accept if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try as follows

```
style="width:<?php echo $value.'%'; ?>;"
```

Comment: Please check it now.

Comment: @D4V1D `;` isn't needed before `?>`.

Comment: @Barmar: How come? Every PHP statements must finish with a `;` right?

Comment: It's a special case, since `?>` ends PHP statement parsing, so it also ends the statement.

Comment: Fair enough, didn't know that. I still think, even though not needed, `;` should be there just to be consistant.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
            include('../../dbconnect.php');
            $id = $_SESSION['ID'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM progress WHERE lectureID=1 AND chapterID = 1 AND currentLevel='novice' AND ID = '$id';";

            $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('Query failed');

            while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $value = $result['chapterPerc'];
                ?>

                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
                     aria-valuenow="<?php echo $value; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $value; ?>%;">
                </div>
                <?php
            } //while loop closes here

            ?>
        </div>
```

It shoud works, beacause you didn't specified the width in the `aria-valuenow` property

Also, try about making `print_r($value);` to be sure it's what you are excepting for.

Comment: The `aria-valuenow` is not mandatory to see the progress bar actually.

Answer (score 1):

> *"The problem was with the query itself there's no chapterID 1 should have written 2. Thanks for the insight. :) – Damini 2 hours ago."*

Rather than `or die('Query failed')` what you should have used was `or die(mysqli_error($con))` in order to get the *real* error.